# VBA Date shown as Number

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and i need to get some rows out of a database.
The Problem is that the Date the first time it is selected is shown in the format `dd.mm.yyyy`, but after some time the date is shown as a whole number like `42814` or something like that.

Here are 2 pictures for better understanding

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]

And here the code

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "ODBC;DSN=OpsApps;UID=Alligatoah;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office 2016;WSID=AT000616;DATABASE=OpsApps" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandText = Array( _
        "SELECT TV.Customer, TV.KNUM, TV.DMRF, TV.BoM, TV.Costs, TV.PlnLaunch, TV.Date, TV" _
        , _
        "_.ActualCosts" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM OpsApps.dbo.TV TV" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "WHERE (TV.SystemMCSDate>={ts '2017-01-01 00:00:00'})" _
        )
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Query_from_VillachOpsApps"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

Can  anyone help?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Add the desired formatting (to the date column) in the end of the code.

Comment: You don't need to use `& Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) &` - just use `& vbCrLf &` instead.

Comment: Also, is it a national standard in your country to separate date sections using a `.` or a `/`? If it's okay, then fair enough, but if it's not standard then save yourself lot's of heartache later by using the standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set the [**`NumberFormat`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-numberformat-property-excel) property of your range

For example, if I have `18/08/17` in a cell and then convert its `NumberFormat` manually in the Excel ribbon to "general", we see `42965`. You can specify this format in VBA using a string like so:

```
' Use your column here, could also use a table range
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet").Columns("F").NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"
```